# Hosting on firebase showing blank page

Tags: vue.js, firebase-hosting

I have checked tutorials and blog post but coudn't find solution to my problem. Hosting on firebase showing blank page consistently.

firebase.json file

```
 {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am just unable to figure out the problem even after many deployment to firebase

Screenshot
[image: dist folder]

Comment: It sounds like your `dist` folder does not contain your web site then. It's hard to say why that is without more information.

Comment: The project was built successfully with out errors and dist folder is populated, is there any way to verify the dist folder if it actually contain my website files?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the folders in your Firebase project?

Comment: I have the feeling you are somehow mixing up the two projects. When you build your vue.js app, a set of files are created in the `dist` folder of the vue.js project. These files shall be under the folder configured via hosting/public in your **Firebase project**. Are you sure the dist folder is under the Firebase project?

Comment: vue.config.js was configured to publicpath node.env i just change it to BASE.URL andmy app was served successfully. THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR CONTRIBUTIONS